# What is the projection used by MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I am storing a number of point features inside a SQLite database for display inside of MKMapView and I would like to precompute and store coordinates in the the projection of the map instead of in lat/lon (for index/performance reasons). However, I am creating this database externally (in Python), so I cannot simply use the MKMapPointForCoordinate() function. What is the projection used by MKMapView? The documentation states that it is a  [mercator projection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html) but it does not appear to be the [web mercator](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) projection that I expected. How can I compute an X/Y coordinate from a Lat/Lon ?

Comment: Please post the code.. that will help us to better understand the problem

Answer (score 3):

Personally I feel you're approaching the problem from the wrong angle - you say don't want to store latitude/longitude co-ordinates for 'index/performance reasons'. What are these reasons?

Storage, indexing, and querying of geographic coordinates inside of a database is not an unusual problem. They are simply two decimal numbers, making indexing and querying very straightforward.

Apple also tell you only to save co-ordinates rather than `MKMapPoints` in their own documentation:

> When saving map-related data to a file, you should always save coordinate values (latitude and longitude) and not map points.

Perhaps you could share some of the issues you're having saving co-ordinates to a database?

Comment: I take your point about Apple's recommendations in the documentation. I did not see this. Presumably they do this so that they have the freedom to change the projection in the future. Still, there are numerous reasons you might want to know the projection. I want to try speeding up the query by aggregating the features into rectangular tiles. This works much better if the tiles are in mapping coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it is webmercator because the overlay tiles I have produced are in that projection and they fit. But like other conmenters said, you're advised to store them in lat/long. If you want to query results in a grid lat/long provide a pretty good starting point. The grid isn't square as you leave the equator but it is rectangular.